# Can I configure IDLE to automatically convert tabs to spaces?

Tags: python, python-idle

I know that spaces are preferred over tabs in Python, so is there a way to easily convert tabs to spaces in IDLE or does it automatically do that?

Comment: IDLE isn't much of an IDE.

Comment: IDLE isn't much of an IDE, AND it already prefers spaces over tabs. Just press your tab key and IDLE will add spaces. I don't think it's even possible to change it to support tabs.

Comment: Did you check?  This is trivial to verify.

Comment: @Blender Why do you write that IDLE isn't an IDE ? (or maybe I don't understand the english expression "isn't much of"). See here (http://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html): _"IDLE is the Python IDE built with the tkinter GUI toolkit."_

Comment: Markus, same interrogation for you (I couldn't put @Markus Meskanen after @Blender)

Comment: @eyquem *"IDLE isn't much of and IDE."* means that IDLE sure is an IDE, but it's not a good one. IDLE barely fulfills the requirements of an IDE and there are so many things that it lacks from a modern IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the IDLE [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/idle.html#automatic-indentation):

> `Tab` inserts 1-4 spaces (in the Python Shell window one tab).

You can also use `Edit > Untabify Region` to convert tabs to spaces (for instance if you copy/pasted some code into the edit window that uses tabs).

---

Of course, the best solution is to go download a real IDE. There are [plenty](http://pydev.org/) of [free](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) [editors](http://www.sublimetext.com/) that are much better at being an IDE than IDLE is. By this I mean that they're (IMO) more user-friendly, more customizable, and better at supporting all the things you'd want in a full-featured IDE.

Comment: Downvoted for "get a real IDE". There is a place for IDLE, and better places to start editor wars.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately IDLE does not have this functionality. I recommend you check out [IdleX](http://idlex.sourceforge.net/features.html), which is an improved IDLE with tons of added functionality.

Comment: IDLE behaves this way by default (at least in the edit window)... And the command `Edit > Untabify Region` converts tabs to spaces. What functionality don't you think it has?

Answer (score 1):

In IDLE 3.6.5, it's **Format** > Untabify Region